# Element not removed from collection with .splice(index, 1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a `$scope.inventories` that contains inventories I can select.
I want to remove the selected item from `inventories` when something is selected, but that does not happen.

Here is the code:

```
  $scope.select = (inventory, index) ->
    url          = '/tasks/select_inventory'
    inventory_id = inventory.id
    $http(
      method: 'POST'
      url: url
      params: { task_id: task_id, inventory_id: inventory_id }
    ).success((data, status) ->
      $scope.selected_inventories.push inventory
      $scope.inventories.splice(index, 1)
      return true
    ).error (data, status) ->
      alert('failed')
      return
```

**The inventory model**

```
angular.module('orwapp').factory 'Inventory', ['$resource', ($resource) ->

  Inventory = $resource "/api/v1/inventories/:id",
                      { id: "@id" }

  return Inventory
]
```

The Rails API returns `@task` as json. Is that OK?
`render json: @task`

Why does not `$scope.inventories.splice(index, 1)` work as expected?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code _should_ work. Are you using $scope.apply() properly to update the scope? What do you see if you `console.log($scope.inventories)` right after you `.splice` it?

Comment: @DanielMa, it sais: [Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, $promise: Promise, $resolved: true]0: Resource1: Resource2: Resource3: Resource$promise: Promise$resolved: truelength: 4__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Is $scope.inventories an Array or keyed object?

Comment: Array, I think. It's populated like this:  $scope.inventories = Inventory.query(task_id: task_id)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a typo, looks like an extra open parens "(" before data

```
).success((data, status) ->
```